# Selectors name when naming directives

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have seen directives in Angular2, be given names in two ways that seems to be working the same:

> 1st  `@Directive({ selector: '[myDirective]' })`
>
> 2nd `@Directive({ selector: 'myDirective' })`

what is the difference of the two?

I have also seen directives like below, which confuses me more

```
@Directive({
    selector: "[ngModel][typeValidate]",
    host: {
        "(input)": "validate($event)"
    }
})
```

Anyone could shed some light?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `selector` property of the `@Directive` decorator is a [**CSS selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors) -- [see "Directive Configuration" at the cheatsheet](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/cheatsheet.html). And, as such:

- The selector `[myDirective]` matches all elements with an **attribute** `myDirective`.

  - Example: `<some-tag myDirective="doesnt matter"></some-tag>`
- The selector `myDirective` matches all elements that have `myDirective` as tag

  - Example: `<myDirective></myDirective>`
- Similarly, `[ngModel][typeValidate]` matches all elements with both an attribute `ngModel` and `myDirective`.

  - Example: `<some-tag myDirective="a" ngModel="b"></some-tag>`

Answer (score 2):

Think of selector as CSS selectors,

> Specifies a CSS selector that identifies this directive within a
>   template. Supported selectors include element, [attribute], .class,
>   and :not(). Does not support parent-child relationship selectors.

so `myDirective` is a element selector

```
 <myDirective></myDirective>
```

and `[myDirective]` is an attribute selector

```
 <div myDirective=""></div>
```

Hope this helps!!